# Creating dynamic form in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a form on thymeleaf where i have a dropdown as the first field and based on the selection from this dropdown, other fields would appear dynamically.
I am thinking to use  to take the data from this dropdown and then shows remaing fields.

What i have created (rough):

```
</div>
            <script>
function singleSelectChangeValue() {
    //Getting Value
    //var selValue = document.getElementById("singleSelectDD").value;
    var selObj = document.getElementById("singleSelectValueDDJS");
    var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
    //Setting Value
    document.getElementById("textFieldValueJS").value = selValue;
    document.getElementsByName("textFieldValueJS").value=selValue;
}

</script>

<select id="singleSelectValueDDJS" class="form-control"
                    onchange="singleSelectChangeValue()">
  <option value="0">Select Value 0</option>
  <option value="8">Option value 8</option>
  <option value="5">Option value 5</option>
  <option value="4">Option value 4</option>
</select>

<form>
 <td>
    <a th:if="${textFieldValueJS == '8'}">Code for Remaining input fields for value 8</a>
    <a th:if="${textFieldValueJS == '5'}">Codefor Remaining input fields for value 5</a>
and so on....
</td>
</form>
```

This does not seem to be working. I am not sure if i am going to the right direction.
If there is any other way we can do this, please let me know.

Comment: What type of error are you getting? Have you traced your console?

Comment: Where are the dynamic form data is declared? From where do you want to get the dynamic form data and then set it as the form? And also where exactly you are stuck? Are you getting any errors? Is your JavaScript not working?